# skipping footer and header with sed command

Tags: sed

I have a command

```
sed -e 's/\\N//g' ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${OUTPUT_SED_FILE_NAME} > ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
```

I want to remove the header and footer from the source file. What switch I need to put in the sed line.

Thanks,

Comment: you mean remove first & last line?

Comment: Why is the variable ${OUTPUT_SED_FILE_NAME} being used as the *input* to sed?  Variable names should be descriptive rather than obfuscatious.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Obfuscatious 

Comment: Yes - please. The first and last lines. The variables are part of the script - so ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ seq 5 | sed '1d; $d'
2
3
4
```

Comment: By "the above statement" do you mean your question? If so just click the `edit` button under it.